# (Java) Can I create an object and use a setter on the same line?

Tags: java, eclipse, object, variables, setter

Is it possible to create an object in JAVA and then instantly use a setter on the same line?

Like this: `Class classname = new Class()`**.setSomething("String");**

How can I do it correctly, eclipse always says :

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to type Class

Comment: I think what you want is called Builder Pattern. You can't do it in your case, because setter does not have a return value

Comment: possible only if setter returns Class object, but it is not recommended

Comment: `new Class().setSomething("String");` is perfectly fine, however assigning that line to `Class classname` is not unless the method `setSomething `returns an object of type `Class`

Comment: You might want to consider creating a constructor that takes a parameter instead.

Answer (score 4):

The error you're getting is just because the return value of `setSomething()` is `void`. E.g. the method looks like this;

```
public void setSomething(String something){
    this.something = something;
}
```

And because `void` is not assignable to anything you can't create your object inline and call a method on it. But it still is possible when changing the signature to something like this:

```
class MyClass{
    private String something;

    public MyClass setSomething(String something){
        this.something = something;
        return this; // returning this
    }
}
```

This use of `return this` is called `method-chaining` and can be seen mostly in the builder pattern.

Whilst the above may work you probably want to always set `something` to a value when creating an instance of `MyClass`. To do this, you have to add a custom constructor which accepts an initial value for `something`. E.g:

```
class MyClass{

    private final String something;

    public MyClass(String something){
        this.something = something;
    }
}
```

Which then can be used like the following:

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass("Something");
```

The latter is prefered over the prior. Because that way the object is created with the value set and can not be in an invalid state. (E.g. when no `something` is set, which may lead to nasty `NullPointerException`s).

> **Note:** You may have seen that i used the keyword `final` when declaring the variable `something`. This may be omitted if you want to be able to change `something` later to a different value, but when you're leaving it as is then you've created an immutable `MyClass` instance which is mostly prefered over mutable instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like it using Builder Pattern as @Jens said.

```
public class Car {

   private String brand;

   public Car(String brand) {
      this.brand = brand;
   }

   public static class Builder {

      private String brand;

      public static Builder withBrand(String newBrand) {
         Builder builder = new Builder();
         builder.brand = newBrand;        
         return builder;
      }

      public static Car build() {
         return new Car(this.brand);
      }
   }
}
```

So you can call a new car this way:

```
Car evoque = new Car.Builder().withBrand("Range Rover").build();
```

Builder Pattern is very useful when you have many atributes to set and dont want an extensive constructor.